# React Context always returns EMPTY

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

I have a `Search` parent component and a `SideBar` child component, I am trying to get context in  `SideBar`, but everytime it returns empty.

I followed the tutorial exactly like: https://itnext.io/manage-react-state-without-redux-a1d03403d360
but it never worked, anyone know what I did wrong?

Here is the codesandbox link to the project: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-elion-3li7v

Comment: i dont know what you did but here is a working example of the toturial u used... start from there... https://codesandbox.io/s/o2w7ojw3z?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js:173-210

Comment: I used Spyna's HOC helper functions exactly like the code he wrote but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote that article.

**To solve your specific problem:**

When using the HOC `withStore` you're injecting the prop `store` into the wrapped component: `<WrappedComponent store={context}`.
The value of the prop `store` is an object that contains 3 functions: `get`, `set`, and `remove`.

So, instead of printing it, you should use it. For example `this.props.store.get("currentAlbums")` or `this.props.store.set("currentAlbums", [album1, album2])`.

This example is forked by your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-wood-ycps6

**However**

Don't rewrite the article code, but use the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@spyna/react-store which is already packed, tested, and has more features.

An event better solution is to use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-hook. That is the new version of the one in that article.
This is an example of a sidebar that updates another component content: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-hook-sidebar-xxwkm

**Be careful when using react context API**

Using the React Context API to manage the global state of an application has some performance issues, because each time the context changes, every child component is updated.
So, I don't recommend using it for large projects.

The library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@spyna/react-store has this issue.

The library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-hook does not.

Comment: hi, is there a non-hook version of `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-hook` that does not have the performance issue?

Comment: Well, as you can see here: https://github.com/Spyna/react-store/blob/master/src/withStore.js#L10 that lib uses React.PureComponent as a wrapper. PureComponents (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) implements the method shouldComponentUpdate() and prevents the re-render if no prop is changed. This mitigates in some way the performance issues because the component only runs the shouldComponentUpdate method, but not the render() one.

Comment: If you're interested have a look at the "performance page" here: https://spyna.github.io/react-store/

Answer (score 0):

You pass the store as a prop, so to access it, you need `this.props.store` in your `SideBar`.

Not `this.state.store`

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, I have changed it to `this.props.store`, but it still returns `{}`

Comment: @yelnn not sure what you are trying to do, but the `store` only has the 3 methods in it, at start. You do not get access to the `Search` local state, only to the store state.

Comment: You most likely want to use the provider detached from the `Search` component, and use `withStore` on the `Search` component. And you most likely want to move the shared state to the `store`.

Comment: Finally, keep in mind that functions are not included when you use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I see, I am trying to get the `state` datas of the `Search` Component like `this.props.store.get('something')` in the `SideBar` Child Component

Comment: The `Hoc` `createStore` is supposed to add the `get/set/remove` functions to the `WrappedComponent` ( `Search` ) right?

Comment: @yelnn no, that is what the `withStore` does. The `createStore` creates a provider, and in your case renders a component inside it, but does not add the store methods to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapping App component around Search and Sidebar:

```
const App = props => (
  <div>
    <Search />
    <SideBar />
  </div>
);
export default createStore(App);
```

Now you can manipulate state with set and get that you have available in child components Search and Sidebar.

In Search component you can have something like:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.store.set("showModal", this.state.showModal);
  }
```

also wrapped with withStore(Search) ofc.

and in SideBar you can now call:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {"Sidebar: this.state.store: ---> " +
          JSON.stringify(this.props.store.get("showModal"))}
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and you will get the output.